# how to auto-increment line numbers in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

eclipse (ganymede) is not incrementing the line numbers automatically. On creating a new class it prints line number till 6 (6th line contains closing bracket for class). After writing new lines in class, line number is still 6. To get the line numbers updated I again have to go to... show line number -> uncheck it -> apply -> check it again-> apply.

which setting will allow auto incrementation of line number?

Comment: Can you show an image? Can you try it on a remotely current version?

Comment: here is the image url http://s28.postimg.org/flzechril/Screen_Shot.png